# Programming issue with HACKRF module

Tags: python-3.x, drone.io, uhd

There is a python project with the uhd library....
is it possible to rewrite data reception to the hackRF receiver using the pyHackRF library?
I will send you a project on uhd if necessary

If possible help with the project and give an answer if it is possible at all

```
def set_sdr(usrp, sample_rate=50e6, duration_s=1.3, gain=None):
###### dev config (UHD b200) #####
# RX2 port for 2.4 GHz antenna
usrp.set_rx_antenna("RX2",0)
if gain:
    usrp.set_rx_gain(gain, 0)
else:
    usrp.set_rx_agc(True, 0)

num_samps = duration_s*sample_rate

usrp.set_rx_rate(sample_rate, 0)
dev_samp_rate = usrp.get_rx_rate()

# Set up the stream and receive buffer
st_args = uhd.usrp.StreamArgs("fc32","sc16")
st_args.channels = [0]
_metadata = uhd.types.RXMetadata()
_streamer = usrp.get_rx_stream(st_args)
_recv_buffer = np.zeros((1, RECV_BUFFER_LEN), dtype=np.complex64)

return num_samps, _metadata, _streamer, _recv_buffer
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to receive assistance here in Stack Overflow, you need to include your code and your specific question. How do you wish to rewrite the data reception?